# Scrolling Box File Load/AJAX click event file load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to load a text file into a Scrolling Box (marquee in this case). How do i make it load a text file's data (text contained with in the txt) into a scrolling banner

This is what i have so far - but you have to put the text you want to display inside HTML

```
 <div>
<marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="90" scrollamount="10" behavior="scroll" loop="0" style="position:absolute;left:367px;top:307px;width:613px;height:28px;z-index:9;" id="Marquee2"><span style="color:white;font-family:Arial;font-size:24px;"></span><span style="color:black;font-family:Arial;font-size:24px;"></span>
 <!--------------------------ENTER TEXT FOR BANNER IN HERE---------------------------------->

  THIS IS THE BANNER

 <!--------------------------------------END------------------------------------------------->
 </div>
```

I also have also used this option to load a part of text into a  element. Can i use something similar? With out the click event (rather auto load)?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#heading1").click(function(){
   $("#paragraph1").slideToggle("slow").load("paragraph1.txt #p1");
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#heading2").click(function(){
   $("#paragraph2").slideToggle("slow").load("paragraph1.txt #p2");
  });
});
</script>


  <div>
<h3 id="heading1">Store of the Year</h3>
<div id="paragraph1"></div>

<h3 id="heading2">Stofe of the Year 20134</h3>
<div id="paragraph2"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to have a DB act as an event store and then use a query to pull only the latest (like say 5) events.

Any way, you need to create a function that can be called every time you need to retrieve data:

```
function getFile (success) {
  $.get({
    url: 'full/url/to/access/file.txt', // could be relative path, I'm not sure tbh could some one point that out?
    success: success(dataFromServer),
    dataType: 'text'
  })
}
```

you'd then use it like so:

```
getFile( function success (dataFromServer) {
  data = whateverYouNeedToDoToFormatTextForDisplayOnYourSite
  $("#paragraph2").slideToggle("slow").load(data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick replay - going try that -

Comment: I have managed to make it work vie object element. However i am having problems styling the text

Comment: <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrolldelay="90" scrollamount="10" loop="0" style="position:absolute; left:367px; top:307px; width:613px; height:28px; z-index:9;" id="Marquee2">
    <object type="text/html"    data="ScrollingBanner.txt"></object></marquee>

Comment: Umm, I hesitate to say this but I think the marquee tag was made obsolete in HTML 5, that said, I would use java-script to load the text in from the now downloaded file line by line (i.e. split on new line). Then on each element in the array push it to the marquee, have a wait and then let it loop to the next one in the array. I think, I'll be honest I've never used a marquee tag so I don't know much about it's behavior.

Comment: Ye it has been made obsolete, however i am working with a server, which is using HTML 4. So that is not a problem and i am really bad (below amature) with java.

Comment: I need to style the text this object loads        '<object type="text/html" data="ScrollingBanner.txt"></object>'

Comment: Can't you just give the object a class and then use some css?